# Web server STDERR output color

Tags: meteor

I would really like to change STDERR (web server) colors using Meteor on Windows 7. They are blue at the moment and I can't see it on my Powershell (black background) screen. I spent half day on changing Powershell colors but found out that none of them were blue, so it must be some meteor setting.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try enabling `raw-logs` to remove the colours by passing it as a flag when you run `meteor`

```
meteor --raw-logs
```

Comment: Great solution. Worked straight away. Thank you for quick response.